# How can I make a submit button change color and text when form succesfully submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

my clients wants submit button turns green insted of orange when form succesfully submitted and change text on it. My form use php and its a bit to complex to me to make it work. Please someone help me with that intresting task.

Here is sample of page where you can see form and big orange button.
http://makeme3d.kz/time/time.html

And here is my code

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container form">
       <div class="row">
 <form form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm" novalidate >

 <h2 align="center">Get Free Quote Today and Start Saving</h2>
        <div class="col-md-6 left">

  <div class="control-group ">
    <label class="control-label">Full name</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="name" placeholder="Full name" 
            required  data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label">Business name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bname"  placeholder="Business name"
    required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Business name" />
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-6 right">
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Email"
    required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Email" />
    <p class="help-block"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label">Best contact phone number</label>
    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone"
     required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Phone number" />
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="btn-submit" align="center"> 
<button type="submit" class="btn-custom btn-lg">Click Here to Start Saving</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="success"></div>



    </div>

    </div>




<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="./js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/contact_me.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
    /*
  Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation
   example is taken from jqBootstrapValidation docs 
  */
$(function() {



 $("input,textarea, select").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(
    {
     preventSubmit: true,
     submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // something to have when submit produces an error ?
      // Not decided if I need it yet
     },
     submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
       // get values from FORM
       var name = $("input#name").val();  
       var bname = $("input#bname").val();
           var email = $("input#email").val();
           var phone = $("input#phone").val();   
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
           // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
       firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
         }        
     $.ajax({
                url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {name: name, bname: bname, email: email, phone: phone},
                cache: false,
                success: function() {  
                // Success message
                   $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                   $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append( "</button>");
                  $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');

          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
          },
       error: function() {      
        // Fail message
         $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                 .append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry "+firstName+" it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Could you please email me directly to <a href='mailto:me@example.com?Subject=Message_Me from myprogrammingblog.com'>me@example.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
        //clear all fields
        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
           })
         },
         filter: function() {
                   return $(this).is(":visible");
         },
       });

      $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).tab("show");
        });
  });


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */ 
$('#name').focus(function() {
     $('#success').html('');
  });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
    empty($_POST['bname'])      ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false ;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$bname = $_POST['bname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'me@mail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
                  "Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n  \nBusiness name: $bname \n \nPhone: $phone \n  \nEmail: $email_address\n\n".

$headers = "From: TimeClockWizardSpecialOffering\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: So when the Ajax call comes back set the color and text...

Comment: You can't split html into two parts using jQuery (one append have beginning of the tag and the second one have closing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ajax function being run.

Add the following JS into the success function:

```
$(".btn-custom").css("background-color","green");
$(".btn-custom").val("New Text");
```

Obviously change these as needed.

Comment: I don't really appreciate my superior answer being commented down... -_-